# Auto receipt print generator react js and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, printing, thermal-printer

I am creating a MERN app. I am wondering if I can connect my computer to a printer from an ip address and that printer is far away.
like we connect with ssh or ip address to connect our web server. in which language it is possible just thinking...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

With your app, I think the easiest way is to let the Nodejs handled the auto receipt printing service.

I have created a simple diagram to show you how the system would work.

[image: Receipt printing service]

Comment: Yeah this is so interesting , but i dont know that how can i send data from backend to the thermal printer. Please explain, i need that

Comment: I found that there are some npm packages that can help you to do this. For instance, I found this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-thermal-printer/v/4.0.3

Comment: That's working pretty fine, but what i need is my server and my printer are in two different places then how do i connect my server to the printer? Getting a print is another matter.

Comment: How my server can connect to the printer that is at completely different place?

Comment: You can host the backend in the same network with the Thermo printer, then try to publish the back end to the internet (you can either use port forwarding or port tunnel). After that, you can access the backend anywhere, which mean your website can send a request to the backend from a different network.

Comment: last comment is good close but not clear